# Visual Studio Code extensions are available only in default or first profile

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was using VS Code with the Default profile. I installed (or copied offline) 100+ extensions and I can see them all in `C:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions.`

After some time I created a new profile, which we'll call "P1". All extensions were still available in that profile.

Some time passed again and now I need a second profile ("P2"). So I created a second profile, but I do not see any extensions in VSC when I am using profile P2.

I suppose Profiles works like Environments and I could install some of them again, but I want to have the same extensions (100+) with the same settings and change only a few later. I was thinking, maybe I could export profile P1, open the file (profile), rename and import the profile again? No, importing did nothing.  It did not even create a new profile.

All extensions are stored in one folder, `<user>\.vscode\extensions`. How does VSC know which extensions should be used for which profile, when information about extensions is not part of the profile? How can I duplicate a profile?

Answer (score 0):

> So I created a second profile, but I do not see any extensions in VSC when I am using profile P2.

It should be like that. VS Code profiles each have their own notion of what extensions are installed (each has their own extensions.json file at `Users/profiles/<id>/extensions.json` in [the user data directory](/a/77876923/11107541)), even though they [all share the same directory for storing installed extensions](/a/77729111/11107541).

> but I want to have the same extensions (100+) with the same settings and change only a few later

I think you should be able to run `code --profile <profile name> --list-extensions` and pipe the output into a file, then edit the file as you wish, and then pipe that file into something like `xargs -I % code '--install-extension %'` or read it into a shell loop that installs each one.

> All extensions are stored in one folder, .vscode\extensions. How does VSC know which extensions should be used for which profile, when information about extensions is not part of the profile?

Wrong. Read what I said above about extensions.json in profile directory in user data directory. You could try manually copying that file afterwards if it doesn't get exported with the profile export.